# Regex Word boundary confusion

Tags: .net, regex

From what I read if, I want to capture specific words that I could use word boundaries.

I have the following information

```
First: 12345Z Apr 16 Something WORD: ABC Notification #1234 Key1 Key2 Key3 Key4
Second: 12345Z Apr 16 Something WORD: ABC Notification #1234 Key5 Key3 Key6
Third: 12345Z Apr 16 Something WORD: ABC Notification #1234 Key7 Key6
```

I used the following regex and it will only match `Key7` when I need to match `Key3 Key4 Key6 Key7`

```
(?<=#\d{4}\s)(\b(Key3|Key4|Key6|Key7)\b)
```

Comment: what you are doing will not match any key if it just does not follow after `#1234`

Comment: Thanks for the update I just noticed that as well. Thanks for the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is that your regex does not let anything between the `#`+4 digits and the keys you are interested in. You can easily fix it by adding an optional `(?:\s+\w+)*` pattern to the lookbehind that will match zero or more sequences of 1+ whitespace and 1+ word characters:

```
(?<=#\d{4}(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*\b(Key3|Key4|Key6|Key7)\b
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%23%5Cd%7B4%7D(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B)*)%5Cs*%5Cb(Key3%7CKey4%7CKey6%7CKey7)%5Cb&i=First%3A%2012345Z%20Apr%2016%20Something%20WORD%3A%20ABC%20Notification%20%231234%20Key1%20Key2%20Key3%20Key4%0D%0ASecond%3A%2012345Z%20Apr%2016%20Something%20WORD%3A%20ABC%20Notification%20%231234%20Key5%20Key3%20Key6%0D%0AThird%3A%2012345Z%20Apr%2016%20Something%20WORD%3A%20ABC%20Notification%20%231234%20Key7%20Key6), declare with the verbatim string literal in C# (or use as is in VB.NET) and use with `Regex.Matches`.

A [C# demo](http://ideone.com/P3nt8J):

```
var strs = new List<string> { "First: 12345Z Apr 16 Something WORD: ABC Notification #1234 Key1 Key2 Key3 Key4",
"Second: 12345Z Apr 16 Something WORD: ABC Notification #1234 Key5 Key3 Key6",
"Third: 12345Z Apr 16 Something WORD: ABC Notification #1234 Key7 Key6"};
foreach (var s in strs) {
    var result = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=#\d{4}(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*\b(Key3|Key4|Key6|Key7)\b")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
    foreach (var e in result)
        Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(?:#\d{4}|\G)\s(\b(?:Key3|Key4|Key6|Key7)\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lC4eV3/1)

or this

```
(?:#\d{4}|\G) \b(?:(Key3|Key4|Key6|Key7)|\w+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ9dH4/1)

**Explanation:**
`(?: … )`: Non-capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bU9dN1/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`\G`: Beginning of String or End of Previous Match   [sample](https://regex101.com/r/lD4iM8/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)